# mysql query logic

Tags: mysql, select, logic

I have an sql query which shows the delivery details of a vehicle. ( it uses greatest to fetch max value from a range of colums for each vehicle stop)

```
SELECT deliveryid AS deliverynumber, loadid1 AS loadnumberdate, 
       haulieraccepted AS haulier, 
       greatest(drop1arrivedatetime, drop2arrivedatetime, drop3arrivedatetime, 
                drop4arrivedatetime, drop5arrivedatetime) AS planneddate, 
       date(greatest(ActualDrop1Arrive, ActualDrop2Arrive, ActualDrop3Arrive, 
                     ActualDrop4Arrive, ActualDrop5Arrive )) AS actualenddate,
       mitigation
    FROM deliverydetails
    WHERE deliveryid=44
```

the output is

> ```
> deliverynumber | loadnumberdate | haulier         | planneddate         | actualenddate | mitigation 
> 44             | 484487         | stols transport | 2011-11-26 15:50:00 | 2011-11-26    | customerdelay
> ```

**How can I add to the mysql query to compare columns 'planneddate' and 'actualenddate'?**  if the dates are the same then set the query field to 'ontime' else if actualenddate>planneddate then 'deliverylate'. So ideally I want the following output:

> ```
> deliverynumber | loadnumberdate | haulier         | planneddate         | actualenddate | mitigation    | Status
> 44             | 484487         | stols transport | 2011-11-26 15:50:00 | 2011-11-26    | customerdelay | ontime.
> ```

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement or [`IF` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if). Perhaps something like:

```
SELECT ....,  IF(actualenddate>planneddate,'deliverylate','ontime') AS status FROM ....
```

Answer (score 1):

use mysql if condition and date conversion function to check and display according to....

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your original query as a subquery.  This will rename the columns.  Then, use a `case ... then` clause to add the column.

Assuming your original query works just fine, it would look like this:

```
select
    *,
    case when (... some comparison on 'planneddate' and 'actualenddate' ...) 
         then <true output> 
             else <false output> end
from
    (<your original query>) as myalias;
```

The trick is that the columns from the subquery are renamed, allowing you to use their new names (`planneddate` and `actualenddate`).